# Media plugin Image Crop not working in android

Tags: android, xamarin, cordova-media-plugin

Using media plugin , I tried the code,

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
   AllowCropping = true
});
```

But nothing happening, no crop option showing when I take photo from camera.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mediaplugin#allow-cropping

Comment: I tried this , but not working. Any other solution?

Comment: This works for iOS and UWP platforms

Comment: Is this working in android? If no, then any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the `Readme` part of `MediaPlugin`, you will know that cropping is only supported on iOS and UWP.

And you may check the reply of this [Feature Request](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/215), for Android platform:

> Not possible as we launch the default Android camera and out of control from the library.